# Joining csv file to vector layer in Processing modeler?

Tags: vector, csv, attribute-joins, qgis-2, qgis-modeler

I am trying to join a simple CSV file of values to a vector layer within Processing modeller.

The match would be on an `ID` held by both files. The CSV file has no geometry.

I can do this easily in QGIS, but want to automate the process in Processing modeller. Is this possible?

I have looked through (and tried) a number of the functions but have not found anything that works.

I am using QGIS 2.0.1

Comment: This question is about a year old, and no comments or answers... Just wondering if you found a way to make this work at all.. I'm on QGIS 2.8

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do this in QGIS 2.18.3:

1. Navigate to Processing -> Graphical Modeler
2. Create a new model or open an existing model.
3. Make sure you have a Vector layer and Table available as input. If they aren't in the model, drag them over to the canvas. The Table will refer to your CSV file. You can name it something descriptive like "CSV File".
4. In the Algorithms tab, navigate to QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector general tools -> Join attributes table, and drag this onto your process canvas.
5. In the box that pops up, select the vector for one input layer, the CSV file as the other input layer, and the enter the table fields to join.
6. Navigate to Processing -> Toolbox, and run your saved model from there. You will be prompted to input both layers. You can click "..." to browse to the CSV or layer location if they are not already in your Layers Panel. Click Run to join them.